# Where to store SparkApplication YAML files on Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/sparkoperator) to deploy Spark Operator to GKE. Then I define a `SparkApplication` specification in a YAML file. But after reading the [User Guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/multi-version-support/docs/user-guide.md#working-with-sparkapplications) I still don't understand:

1. Where to store `SparkApplication` YAML files on Kubernetes cluster or Google storage?
2. Is it ok/possible to deploy them along with the Spark Operator Helm chart to the Spark Master container?
3. Is it a good approach to load the `SparkApplication` configurations to Google Storage and then run `kubectl apply -f <YAML GS file path>`

What are the best practices for storing `SparkApplication` configurations on Kubernetes cluster or GS that I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

To address your questions:

1. There are a lot of possibilities to store your `YAML` files. You can store it locally on your PC, laptop or you can store it in the cloud. Going further in that topic, syncing your `YAML` files to version controlled system (for example Git) would be one of the better options because you will have full history of the changes with ability to check what changes you made and rollback if something failed. **The main thing is that the `kubectl` will need access to this files.**
2. There is no such thing as master container in Kubernetes. There is master node. A master node is a machine which controls and manages a set of worker nodes (workloads runtime)
   Please check the official documentation about [Kubernetes components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/).
3. You can put your `YAML` files in your Google Storage (bucket). But you would not be able to run command in a way `kubectl apply -f FILE`. `kubectl` will not be able to properly interpret file location like `gs://NAME_OF_THE_BUCKET/magical-deployment.yaml`.

   One way to run `kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME.yaml` would be to have it stored locally and synced outside.

   You can access the data inside a bucket through `gsutil`.  You could try to tinker with `gsutil cat gs://NAME_OF_THE_BUCKET/magical-deployment.yaml` and try to pipe it into `kubectl` but I would not recommend that approach.

   Please refer to `gsutil` tool [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) in this case and be aware of:

   > The gsutil cat command does not compute a checksum of the downloaded data. Therefore, we recommend that users either perform their own validation of the output of gsutil cat or use gsutil cp or rsync (both of which perform integrity checking automatically).
   >
   > --  *https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cat*

Let me know if you have any questions to this.